# Data transformation - Pivot function issue

Tags: azure-databricks

Input:

[image]

Expected output should be below

[image]

I tried with pivot function it is not working any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and I got below results:***

> **Please follow this code:**

***I created sample data frame as per above requirement:***

```
data = [("a", 100), ("b", 300), ("a", 50), ("c", 70), ("c", 150), ("b", 300)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,["company","value"])
df.show()
```

*Using pivot and group by function .I got this output*

**Code:**

```
 df.groupBy().pivot("company").sum("value").show()
```

**Output:**

[image]